# Spring mvc configuration error in xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am creating an application using spring 3.2 mvc framework. I am using Spring Tool Suite 
 and maven. When i updated jar 3.1 to 3.2 i am getting the following errors in servelet-context.xml and root-context.xml:-

```
cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans:beans'.
cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
```

[image]

Comment: change `<beans:beans xml ...` to `<beans xml ...` that should help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the version as a suffix for your schema locations:

```
.../schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
.../schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
```

Comment: This worked for me  .../schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
.../schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd

Comment: No they should all have the same version. In your case 3.2. I just wrote these two as an example, for sure all the others need to be updated too.

Comment: What is difference between 3.2 and 3.0

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#new-in-3.2

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the version of your spring schema also clean and install the maven project again after defining the schema.